# Where can I find a list of Hibernate validation errors?

Tags: hibernate

Is there a doc/web page that documents all the errors like HV000032 somewhere?
I'm struggling to find it with search engines...

Comment: Don't search for the codes themselves. They can have multiple causes. Better to search for the actual exception it throws with the code

Comment: Thanks but I'm not seraching for a specific exception to solve, I'm searhcing for a list like this for oracle error codes: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/jboss_enterprise_application_platform_continuous_delivery/19/mgmt_model/log-message-reference.html Though as said, its better to search for the actual exception, as these error codes aren't really saying much

Comment: thanks: I did a search with the exception as you suggested but in 5 pages of google hits I did not get this match to the redhat site.I searched restricting to the jboss.org and hibernate.org, but I did not think to search for it restrcting to redhat.